What is a closed orientable 4-dim smooth manifold $M$ with a free $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action such that $M/\mathbb{Z}_2$ is not smoothable?
I have completely no idea how to do this. I know by Freedman classification that there are unsmoothable manifolds whose intersection form is $E_8$ and there is $*\mathbb{C}P^2$ such that $ks(*\mathbb{C}P^2)=1$. But then I do not know how to proceed.
